# What is making this red outline in Visual Studio? And what's the name of the feature?

Tags: visual-studio

[image: Red outlines]

After some update Visual Studio has started showing the above red outline with - sometimes useful - suggestions. What is making this red outline in Visual Studio? And what's the name of the feature?

Comment: It's the [intellicode](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/en/services/intellicode/)

Comment: @ManuelFabbri it's really weird that none of their videos or images shows that red outline though.